# Navigation Drawer onNavigationItemSelected() not responding

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I added a navigation drawer to my app, however, when I click on an icon in the navigation drawer it does not execute the action defined in the onNavigationItemSelected() method. Instead it closes the navigation drawer.
How can I find a way to make sure that when an icon is clicked it does execute the action defined in the onNavigationItemSelected()?

[image: Screen record GIF]

Navigation_Drawer.java

```
public class Navigation_Drawer extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation__drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    setNavigationViewListner();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation__drawer, menu);
    return true;
}

private void setNavigationViewListner(){
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.Logout: {
            User user = new User();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button has been Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button has been Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button has been Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button has been Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (id == R.id.Logout) {
        User user = new User();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation__drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation__drawer_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to take out this line of code...

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

What is happening is that the code is running through your switch statement and if statements and doing the appropriate action, but at the end of your code your are telling it to close the drawer. The return true value indicates that the user is finished and has performed all their actions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the ids in `activity_navigation__drawer_drawer.xml` are the same that are checked inside `onNavigationItemSelected()`?  
Because there is another menu with similar name `navigation__drawer` that I see you inflate in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. 
The 3d of these lines is redundant:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
setNavigationViewListner();
```

it repeats the previous 2 lines by calling `setNavigationViewListner()`.  
Also you check for `R.id.Logout` twice: in `switch` and later in an `else if` statement

Comment: Ok, so do I have to remove the 3 lines that are redundant?

Answer (score 0):

If you have check the button from Toast message so

> Replace **getApplicationContext()** to **this** in Toast
>
> Toast.makeText(this, "button has been Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
> I think this it would be help you.

Comment: There is nothing to do with context . Toast.maketext accepts both contexts . As from documentation : Context: The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.

Comment: @ImLearning i have faced same issue with context.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, Here is my solution.

I was programmatically adding HeaderView to NavigationView Hence I already had NavigationView

I called navigationView.bringToFront();

Here is code snippet for context

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
navigationView.bringToFront();
```